# How can I fix CSS stylesheet path in Express + ESJ project

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have used **Express and EJS** for my project. I would like that when I enter "**localhost:PORT/posts/:articleName**", a .ejs file to be rendered. The only problem is that even if I have `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`it doesn't work like it should. When I am inspecting the stylesheet link in the *post.ejs* file, it is "**localhost:PORT/posts/style.css**". But I want the path to be "**localhost:PORT/style.css**" in order to work. How can I fix the path?

Project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRkNw.jpg

Code for GET request for /

```
app.get("/posts/:articleName", (req, res) => {
for(obj of posts) {
    if(lodash.lowerCase(obj.title) === lodash.lowerCase(req.params.articleName)) {
        console.log("it s a match");
        res.render("post.ejs", {title: obj.title, 
            content: obj.content});
        return;
    }
}
res.redirect("/")
});
```

*posts* = array of JSON objects

*post.ejs* = the file containing only specific article, it doesn't work as it should, because it doesn't load the style.css file from public directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to have a "/" before your css file or put it in another subdirectory to get the correct path

so `link rel="stylesheet href="/style.css"` does work, but `link rel="stylesheet href="style.css"` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant, because you wrote this part of code incorrect:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem, but thank you. FIX: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"> instead of <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">